# How to handle same business rules in two different bounded contexts?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

I am trying to wrap my head around DDD and I have a question regarding a rule in an entity that is inside two bounded contexts.

Let's say I have the `Person` entity in both the `WorkOrder` and `HR` bounded contexts. They have different attributes relative to each bounded contexts but they share some attributes like their address.

Should I duplicate the validation logic for the address ?

What if one bounded contexts has looser constraints on the address ? For instance if the `HR` context required the address to be in the USA but not the `WorkOrder` context. What would stop a write from the `WorkOrder` context to violate the constraint ?

In this case both bounded contexts are in a modular monolith sharing a DB

Answer (score 0):

It depends onto how your business logic flows and how your contexts integrate. DDD advices great tool named [Context Mapping](https://github.com/ddd-crew/context-mapping) which describes bounded contexts and teams contacts with collection of patterns and helps you to learn how your models interact across boundaries. It may help you to understand how your business process flows and **how** rules should be (or not to be) applied. Few examples below:

#### Customer / Supplier

[image: CustSup]

If your `Person` entity in `HR` context emits an event `PersonCreated(Guid Id, string Name, Address Address)` and your `WorkOrder` context translates this event and creates its own `Person` entity, then you can conclude that `WorkOrder` context is downstream and depends onto `HR` context. In short your `WorkOrder` receives `Address` **already validated** by `HR` context business rules. Validating it again same way is useless [[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)], but if you need it you can validate it more strictly as well.

#### Separate Ways

[image: SepWays]

It also may be situation when your `HR` and `WorkOrder` context are independent and do not integrate with each other. In such scenario your `Person` entities will evolve independently and that means you should validate their `Address` separate ways as well :)

#### Shared Kernel

[image: Shared]

If `Address` is a stable concept in your company and widely used across teams you may consider to move it into separate module and share it between your `HR` and `WorkOrder` contexts. All business rules related to `Address` will be used by both teams now.
You should keep such modules as small as possible because overusing it leads to huge coupling problems.

Also it can be other possible solutions based on your problem domain, you should find it by your own and i hope these examples and Context Mapping will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that there isn't a clearly identified bounded context that is the owner of the address field. Usually in DDD if we duplicate a field in one or more contexts there is one bounded context responsible for validating and propagating that state change.

So in your example it might be that the `HR` bounded context owns the address field, anywhere in your application where address is modified or written will rely on the `HR` context, The `HR` context will handle all validations in a single place and propagate a domain event for the address change so for example `WorkOrder` can listen to this event and update it's own address field being certain that the correct validations have been applied by the owning bounded context. In this way they will have a customer supplier relationship, see also:

https://ddd-practitioners.com/home/glossary/bounded-context/bounded-context-relationship/customer-supplier/

Now to look at this problem from another angle, if the `WorkOrder` context not having a country level constraint is an actual business requirement and not just an example of what shouldn't happen, then that would clearly indicate that the address in `WorkOrder` evolves separately from `HR` and has it's own behaviour, in that case you should reevaluate your design and decouple these fields by not sharing validation logic